# Pandas: How to do mathematical calculations on filtered rows based on two column?

Tags: python, pandas

I have below dataframe and I need to do mathematical operations  on filtered rows.

```
data = pd.DataFrame({'name': ['jpy','jpy','eur','usd','usd','usd'],'currency':['jpy_23','jpy_23','eur_15', 'thb_20','thb_20','thb_20'], 
    'sal':[15.0,20.0,25.0,30.0,20.0,15.0 ]})
```

I want to groupby based on two columns like below :

```
df1 = df.groupby(['name','currency'])
```

then I want to do below operations on each group like below:

```
len(data[(data['sal']>25)])/len(data.index)
len(data[(data['sal']<=25)])/len(data.index)
len(data[(data['sal']>=0) & (data['sal']<5)])/len(data.index)
len(data[(data['sal']>=5) & (data['sal']<15)])/len(data.index)
len(data[(data['sal']>=15) & (data['sal']<25)])/len(data.index)
```

And at last the expected dataframe should be like below. The empty column should contain calculated values. Please suggest how to do get the expected output.

```
new_data = pd.DataFrame({'name': ['jpy','eur','usd'],'currency':['jpy_23','eur_15','thb_20'], 
    '>25':[ ], '<= 25': [ ], 'Between 0 & 5': [ ], 'Between 5 & 15' : [ ], 'Between >15 & 25': [ ]})
```

Comment: Please frame your code properly.

Comment: @Surya Lohia. Which part you didnt understand ?

Comment: new_data = pd.DataFrame({'name': ['jpy','eur','usd'],'currency':['jpy_23','eur_15','thb_20'], 
    '>25':[ ], '<= 25': [ ], 'Between 0 & 5': [ ], 'Between 5 & 15' : [ ], 'Between >15 & 25': [ ]}) . Please frame this code properly or else provide the output of the dataframe . Its very difficult to understand the content of the dataframe.

Comment: The empty column should contain calculated values as I mentioned above. Thats why I left it blank. I did on whole data as above but not on grouped data.

Answer (score 2):

May be:

```
In [4]: bins = [0, 5, 15, 25, float("inf")]
   ...: groups = data.groupby(['name', 'currency', pd.cut(data['sal'], bins)])
   ...: d = groups.size().unstack()
   ...: d.div(d.sum(axis=1), axis=0)
Out[4]:
sal            (0.0, 5.0]    (5.0, 15.0]   (15.0, 25.0]  (25.0, inf] 
name currency                                                        
eur  eur_15             0.0      0.000000      1.000000      0.000000
     jpy_23             NaN           NaN           NaN           NaN
     thb_20             NaN           NaN           NaN           NaN
jpy  eur_15             NaN           NaN           NaN           NaN
     jpy_23             0.0      0.500000      0.500000      0.000000
     thb_20             NaN           NaN           NaN           NaN
usd  eur_15             NaN           NaN           NaN           NaN
     jpy_23             NaN           NaN           NaN           NaN
     thb_20             0.0      0.333333      0.333333      0.333333
```

Comment: I need the combination with 'name' and 'currency'. Then need to do the calculation on each group and populate the computed value. For example: len(data[(data['sal']>=0) & (data['sal']<5)])/len(data.index)

Comment: Well, you can always add the desired column in groupby, updated.

Comment: How to add a column using this operation len(data[(data['sal']>=0) & (data['sal']<5)])/len(data.index) on group data.

Comment: You mean `[0, 5)`?

Comment: No. i am calculating the percentage of 'count of JPY - JPY_23' in [0,5) divided by total count in the dataset.

Comment: Oh, I see now, then you only need to using `div` on `sum`: `df.div(df.sum(axis=1), axis=0)`. Updated